# select query does not work - Android Sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've a problem with SELECT query that does not return any value, but if I put a real string instead of a variable it works

> db.returnArray("Hi"); // this works
>
> db.returnArray(ChecklistName); // this does not work

Here is the code.

```
    private void shareChecklist(String CheckListName) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    /** sharing code is working but the problem with how to get the item =) */

    //Build the Share Content 
    String shareBody=sCheckList+ " item/s: \n";
    
        db = new SQLiteDB(this.getApplicationContext());
    String[] printItem =db.returnArray(CheckListName);
    
    for(int j=0;j<printItem.length;j++){
        shareBody+=printItem[j]+" \n";
    }

    //Create a Send Intent
    Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    
    //Set the Sharing Type
     sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");

    //Pass Content to the Intent
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, sCheckList+" Check list,I am sharing one of my Check list On Voz App");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
        
    //Create a Chooser
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));    
}
```

SQLiteDataBase Code:

```
     /*** Table ****/
    private static final String TABLE_ITEMS = "items";
private static final String ITEM_ID = "id";
private static final String ITEM_CHECKLISTIDX = "checklistName";
private static final String ITEM_NAME = "itemname";
private static final String ITEM_FLAG = "flag";
private static final String ITEM_DATETIME = "esttime";
private static final String[] ITEMCOLUMNS = { ITEM_ID, ITEM_CHECKLISTIDX,
        ITEM_NAME, ITEM_FLAG, ITEM_DATETIME };
   /*************************************************************/

    /** return an array with items from items table ***/
     public String[] returnArray(String checkName){
    
    String[] items;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query="SELECT * FROM items WHERE checklistName='"+ checkName + "'";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    items=new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int counter=0;

      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                items[counter++]+= cursor.getString(2);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            db.close();
      } 
     return items;
}
```

The table is created so:

```
String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE items ( "+ "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  , " + "checklistName TEXT, "+ "itemname TEXT, " + "flag INTEGER, " + "esttime TEXT )";
db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE);
```

Comment: did you try to debug what the value of `CheckListName` is?

Comment: Please provide more information. What have you tried? what is the value of CheckListName? what errors do you get? simply stating that it does not work is very vague and makes it tough to help.

Comment: Can you show the code where you create the table?

Comment: Just check by removing the single quote

Comment: @Sania : that would consider the variable passed as a column name, which is unlikely to be what the OP is trying to do

Comment: @sbrichards it doesn't give me any errors, This is a check list app, you can add check list, then add a list of items to it, Then I want to share it via any app such as twitter, email...etc. Here I wanna pass the name of the check list to give me its items.

Comment: @Sania I tried, it gave me an error

Comment: "SELECT * FROM items WHERE checklistName= "+ checkName ; I am saying like this.m too working on db.it works for me

Comment: @Sania it doesn't work with me =(

Comment: @Sania it doesn't make any difference =), 'cuz if I put a name of any check list instead of a variable it works correctly

Comment: Den try in rawquery(query, new string[]{checklist} and " SELECT * FROM items WHERE checklistName=?"; if it doesn't work den chk ur db or else post ur error

Comment: @BobMalooga `String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE items ( "+ "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  , " + "checklistName TEXT, "+ "itemname TEXT, " + "flag INTEGER, " + "esttime TEXT )"; db.execSQL(CREATE_ITEM_TABLE);`

Answer (score 1):

You target the wrong field in your SELECT.
Since you are creating this field:

```
checklistidx
```

As in your:

```
String CREATE_ITEM_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE items ( "+ "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  , " + "checklistidx TEXT, "+ "itemname TEXT, " + "flag INTEGER, " + "esttime TEXT )";
```

Your select's WHERE should target that field:

```
String query="SELECT * FROM items WHERE checklistidx = '"+ checkName + "'";
```

instead of

```
String query="SELECT * FROM items WHERE checklistName = '"+ checkName + "'";
```

Comment: I just changed here to checklistName to make the query very understandable, but in the code I used checklistidx in each part =),

Comment: You shouldn't change your code to make it "more understandable", if this change introduces errors.